# Getting product stock levels / quantities in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, stock, quantity

I have the following code to get a product collection but how do I also return back the stock levels too

```
$products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: stock levels? .

Answer (score 0):

Is this the best way

```
$products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: This completely ignores the new inventory system, so the reported stock wont include reservations.